# How to use compareTo within a Generic array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, compareto

I am trying to figure out how to compare two items within a T[] array, here is what I have:

```
public static <T extends Comparable< ? super T>> T getLargest(T [] a, int low, 
               int high){
    if(low>high)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    T[] arrCopy = (T[]) new Object[high-low];
    for(int i=low;i<high;i++){
        if(a[i].compareTo(a[i-1])>0)
            arrCopy[i]=a[i];
        else
            arrCopy[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    return arrCopy[0];
}
```

and then I get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;`

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: You're missing a "throws" clause in your method header, specifically a "throws IllegalArgumentException".

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE IllegalArgumentException is a runtime exception and does not need to be declared

Comment: That must be the most roundabout version to implement a max() method ever thought of xX You obviously don't need any array here.

Comment: @Voo: i don't think it implements maximum

Comment: @newacct Well it isn't working for several reasons and I've a hard time understanding why anyone would write such a function. But I go by the simple deduction: A function that is called `getLargest()` should return the maximum value ;)

Comment: Couldn't you simply make a copy of that particular item of that array and then compare it to another copy from a different array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the array like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] arrCopy = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), high-low);
```

Although the unchecked warning is necessary, this should actually be safe.

Btw, if you want to find the largest element in an array, here's a oneliner:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(final T[] data) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(data));
}
```

For the complete problem you can use one of these two (they are equivalent):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maxA(final T[] data,int from, int to) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, from, to)));
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maxB(final T[] data,int from, int to) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(data).subList(from, to));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work perfectly, but I need to give the slice in the array where I want to look the largest number, int low and int high.

Comment: @fgualda87 ok, combine my oneliner with Arrays.copyOfRange(), see my update

Comment: I think List.subList is preferable, as it doesn't copy any data - it's just a view.

Comment: @Puce in princible, yes, but Arrays.copyOfRange() uses System.arrayCopy() which uses native system routines and is extremely fast

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier in that way to make it recursive??

Comment: And you can use  "<T extends Comparable<? super T>>"

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: a fast copy implementation is still slower and takes more memory than just a view, which doesn't copy at all.

Comment: I mean like making it recursive without having to import Collections

Comment: @fgualda87: What do you want to do recursivly?

Comment: Compare the first item in the array with the rest? Like how would you do it without having to import other libraries?

Comment: @fgualda87 however you do it, it will be horribly inefficient if you don't use System.arrayCopy internally

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd you are right. I used copyOfRange(). Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you create an entire new array when you only care about 1 object, but the issue has nothing to do with generics.  you can't cast an `Object[]` to some more specific type like `String[]`, just like you can't write `String s = new Object()`.

seeing as you only care about the largest value, it would make much more sense to only track 1 value (the biggest value seen so far), not the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error here:

```
T[] arrCopy = (T[]) new Object[high-low];
```

You cannot cast the mother object of all objects (java.lang.object) to anything that has java.lang.comparable as the lowest common denominator, so the exception is thrown. An object (as in java.lang.object) does not implement java.lang.comparable.

In your specific example, you would need to create an array of T (or at the very least java.lang.comparable).

Comment: You actually *cannot* construct arrays of type `T`. For example, have a look at how `java.util.ArrayList` is implemented.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga true, but given an existing array, you can access it's component type (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to assume that an array of `Object` instances is fit for treatment as an array of `Comparable` instances. You're forcibly casting `Object` down to `T`, which we expect extends `Comparable`, but that unchecked assignment isn't even necessary here.

Instead, consider an implementation that does not copy any of the array:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
T getLargest(T[] a, int first, int last)
{
  // Don't tolerate an empty range:
  if (first >= last)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  // Eventually checked by subsequent use of array index operator:
  if (first < 0 || first >= a.length ||
      last < 0 || last >= a.length)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

  T largest = a[first];
  while (++first != last)
  {
    final T candidate = a[first];
    if (candidate.compareTo(largest) > 0)
      largest = candidate;
  }
  return largest;
}
```

Alternately, use [`Collections#max()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29), supplying your array viewed as a `List` after passing it through [`Arrays#asList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(final T[] data, int fromIndex, 
               int toIndex) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(data).subList(fromIndex, toIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `new Object[high-low];` to `new Comparable[high-low];`. Generics are erased to their lower bound, so T is erased to Comparable.